# Why outlet get nil if more top-level views are in XIB

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

Why **outlet to view called *second* get nil** in *willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:*? There is two top-level views in the xib, and *first* and *second* outlet are pointing to them. Is it not allowed to have two top level view in one XIB? I use XIB with UIViewController. *second* outlet still exist in *viewDidLoad* method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to set up property as **strong**, instead of **weak**. And because there is no pointer referring to the *second* view, it get released.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *first;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *second;
```

Comment: Indeed. Top level nib objects need a strong reference. After that all the objects below it can be set to weak references.